# how to run firefox under a debugger using visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, firefox, visual-studio-debugging

i am new to firefox development so i completed first 2 steps given here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction

now in step 3 they are saying that run firefox under a debugger so please tell me how can i run firefox under a debugger or visual studio 2010 debugger?

i am also having firefox 9.0.1 installed on my system.

Comment: Point your debugger at firefox.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to open VS.NET 2005 and then do File > Open > Project/Solution.... This will start the Open Dialog, and you should navigate to firefox.exe located in the dist\bin directory within the objdir you specified in .mozconfig (e.g., mk_add_options MOZ_OBJDIR=@TOPSRCDIR@/firefox-objdir). [NOTE: for me that's C:\proj\mozilla\firefox-objdir\dist\bin\firefox.exe]

Read more here..  https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~david.humphrey/writing/debugging-firefox.html

Answer (score 4):

Mozilla have article about that : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Debugging_Mozilla_on_Windows_FAQ

I hope this explains you what is needed.